# What does it mean to have parenthesis when declaring a string variable?

Tags: c#, vb6

I'm converting VB6 to C#.  I have no experience with VB6.  What's the difference between:

`sWords() As String`

and

`sWords As String`

It's easy to see I can convert the second one to `string sWords` in C#, but the first I dunno what that means..array?

Comment: P.Brian if you have issues or trouble converting VB methods to C# let me know I have converted 7 Different Enterprise level VB.net apps with in the last 6 months to C# VB SUCKS in my Opinion it's to interpreted ....

Comment: @DJKraze - Hey I might take you up on that.  Got an email you want to share?

Comment: I see you are in Dallas..LOL I am in Plano

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The first is an array of type String, the second is just a String.

So the equivalents would be

```
string[] swords
```

and

```
string swords
```

Answer (score 9):

The first is an array whose bounds are determined at runtime.

So you could do:

```
Dim arr() As String
arr = Array("love","to","code")
```

You could also resize the array at runtime:

```
ReDim arr(1 To 50)
```